# Does flatMapMerge cache flows?

Tags: function, kotlin

I wonder how flatMapMerge works in this code:

```
fun requestFlow(i: Int): Flow<String> = flow {
    emit("$i: First") 
    delay(500) // wait 500 ms
    emit("$i: Second")    
}

    fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> { 
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() // remember the start time 
        (1..3).asFlow().onEach { delay(100) } // a number every 100 ms 
            .flatMapMerge { requestFlow(it) }                                                                           
            .collect { value -> // collect and print 
                println("$value at ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime} ms from start") 
            } 
    }

    1: First at 136 ms from start
    2: First at 231 ms from start
    3: First at 333 ms from start
    1: Second at 639 ms from start
    2: Second at 732 ms from start
    3: Second at 833 ms from start
```

After `requestFlow` sleeps for 500 ms, it continues with `emit("$i: **Second**")`. Looking at the output, I am confused. My questions are

1. Has `flatMapMerge` invoked `asFlow` on (1..3) again. Or
2. Does it cache the flow of 1..3 somewhere for later use because `requestFlow` has told it, ' I'm not done yet'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire sequence is like this:

- 1 is emitted from original flow and passed to `requestFlow` which creates a new flow builder which prints "1: First at..." and then suspends for 500ms.
- 2 is emitted from original flow and passed to `requestFlow` which creates a new flow builder which prints "2: First at..." and then suspends for 500ms. (here we have two suspended functions in memory).
- 3 is emitted from original flow and passed to `requestFlow` which creates a new flow builder which prints "3: First at..." and then suspends for 500ms. (here we have three suspended functions in memory).
- After 500ms from 1st emission, the first suspended function resumes and prints "1: Second at ..."
- After 100ms, the second function resumes and prints "2: Second at ..."
- After another 100ms, the last suspended function resumes and prints "3: Second at ..."

`flatternMapMerge` just applies the transformation you provide and returns a `Flow<String>`. Note that this is **not** a suspend function and so returns immediately.

Answering your two questions,

- No, the `asFlow` function is not invoked again.
- It's not caching the flow, just suspending the functions for 500ms, doing other stuff till then, and resuming from where it left off after the delay is over.

Comment: Genius! I wish the document had been written this way. JetBrains is looking for a technical writer. You should definitely apply.